# Flutter Web, weird Text issue, image attached

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart-webui, flutter-web

Check the 2nd Text, even style is same in all `GridView` Item.

Why the Email,mobile text looks different?

Rest in whole app text is like little blur text as shown here.

[image: FlutterWeb text issue]